# How to Check blob size before inserting with ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, blob, oracle-apex

I need to check file size before inserting on oracle table with oracle apex, that user can not be able attach a big size file for uploading.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
dbms_lob.getlength(Upload_blob);
```

Also take a look at this example: [How to upload an image (file) into a table (BLOB)](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4090790)

Comment: HiThanks for reply, That function calculate number of file name char, not calculate the size of file

Comment: @aliyousef  When applied to a BLOB (Binary LOB) `dbms_lob.getlength` returns the number of bytes (size)

Comment: @aliyousef I think you are applying the function to a file name not a file itself - that's why you are getting 'number of file name char'. Take a good look at the example (in the provided link)